# How can I declare and use a *constant* array in a WGSL vertex shader?

Tags: webgpu, wgsl

## Background

I'm trying to render a single triangle by encoding the vertices directly in my WGSL vertex shader.

My idea was to have a global constant array, `TRI_VERTICES` contain the vertices of the triangle, from which I will look up the appropriate vertex coordinates using the builtin `vertex_index`.

```
let TRI_VERTICES: array<vec4<f32>, 3> = array<vec4<f32>, 3>(
  vec4<f32>(0., 0., 0., 1.0),
  vec4<f32>(0., 1., 0., 1.0),
  vec4<f32>(1., 1., 0., 1.0),
);

@vertex
fn vs_main(
  @builtin(vertex_index) in_vertex_index: u32,
) -> @builtin(position) vec4<f32> {
  return TRI_VERTICES[in_vertex_index];
}

@fragment
fn fs_main(@builtin(position) in: vec4<f32>) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
  return vec4<f32>(in.x, in.y, 0.1, 1.0);
}
```

I am running a draw call (in Rust and [wgpu](https://wgpu.rs/)) using `3` vertices and `1` instance as follows:

```
render_pass.draw(0..3, 0..1);
```

Unfortunately, I get the following error:

```
Shader validation error:
   ┌─ Shader:13:9
   │
13 │   return TRI_VERTICES[in_vertex_index];
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ naga::Expression [3]


    Entry point vs_main at Vertex is invalid
    Expression [3] is invalid
    The expression [1] may only be indexed by a constant
```

## Question

The above seems easily fixed if I just change `let TRI_VERTICES` to `var<private> TRI_VERTICES`, but I'm not sure if this is the "correct" solution. What I would like to know is:

- Does using `var<private>` mean that the array entries are mutable within `vs_main`?
- If so, is there a way to declare `TRI_VERTICES` as "constant" somehow?
- What is the most appropriate way to declare `TRI_VERTICES`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following compiles correctly in Tint. This maybe a case of Naga needing to catchup to spec changes, you can file Naga issues at https://github.com/gfx-rs/naga.

```
const TRI_VERTICES = array(
  vec4(0., 0., 0., 1.),
  vec4(0., 1., 0., 1.),
  vec4(1., 1., 0., 1.),
);

@vertex
fn vs_main(
  @builtin(vertex_index) in_vertex_index: u32,
) -> @builtin(position) vec4<f32> {
  return TRI_VERTICES[in_vertex_index];
}

@fragment
fn fs_main(@builtin(position) in: vec4<f32>) -> @location(0) vec4<f32> {
  return vec4(in.x, in.y, .1, 1);
}
```

To answer the questions:

1. A `var<private>` is mutable in the vertex shader but only visible to the current invocation.
2. The new `const` keyword is the new constant.
3. The spec allows dropping most of the type annotations, so declaring as above should be sufficient.

Comment: Although, it looks like the generated HLSL is incorrect in Tint at the moment, filed https://bugs.chromium.org/p/tint/issues/detail?id=1653 on the Tint side.

Comment: The Tint HLSL generation is now fixed, it will slowly roll into Chrome builds.